# UK comic strip from the late 70's. A girl, a crow, & a scarecrow, trapped and about to be served up to a monster's "seedlings"

Tags: story-identification, comics

I vividly recall what I think was the last frame of a comic strip in a UK publication that I read in the late 1970's.  The girl protagonist and her 2 companions are tied up and trapped inside something like a cauldron, whilst a nearby monster (possibly plant-based) gloats and declares that it is going to feed them to its "seedlings".  That one image seared itself onto my impressionable mind.  I'd love to see it again, and know what comic it appeared in and the title of the strip.

- I think that the title of the strip was something like "The 3 Crows".
- The three protagonists were a crow, a scarecrow, and a girl whose name was probably bird or crow-related.
- The style of the strip was in the vein of IPC/Fleetway comics, as opposed to Beano/Dandy style.

That's the sum total of the facts that I can remember, but here are a few impressions:

- The strip was the sort that could be found in Monster Fun comic. It certainly would have been a good fit for that comic.
- It's also possible that the strip was from a female-oriented UK comic (I have two sisters and so there were plenty of those publications lying around the house).
- It's possible that the strip was from a hardcover annual, as opposed to a weekly publication.  If so, the publication date could be from anytime in the 70's.
- I don't recall reading any other installments, and certainly never found out how they got out of the predicament, so it was possibly just a one-off story or maybe a short-run series.
- The word "seedlings" was definitely used in that final frame.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a very nice, complete question.  But just in case there anything else that you might be able to add, we have a list of [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/101407) (and some linked pages) that include every possible detail we've been able to brainstorm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Phone the Crows*  from [Topper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Topper_comic_strips) comic.

A short-lived strip that ran from issue 1211 to 1235.
I remember it only vaguely. Can't tell you the name of the characters. Can't even find any images online.

Comment: The timing is right, and the title certainly has the right feel to it.  I suspect you have the  correct answer here, but I'll hold off from marking this as Answered for a little while in case anyone can fill in the blanks.  (Like you, I'm struggling to find any further information about the strip online)